# multiple chi-squared tests for pairwise comparisons

Tags: spss, chi-squared-test

I have one between-subject factor with four levels, and one dichotomous dependent variable. I want to test if each pair within the between-subject factor is related differently with the dependent variable (So if the first level scores more ‘ones’ on the dependent variable than the second level, if the first level scores more ‘ones’ on the dependent variable than the third level etc.).

The only way I can think of to do this, is to perform six pairwise (2x2) chi-squared tests. Is this the way to answer my question, and if it is, how can I control for type-1-error inflation?

Comment: Six pairwise tests would indeed be one way to do it. There are [numerous ways to control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate#Controlling_procedures) overall type I error rate.

Comment: If you are not comfortable with the assumption that all null hypotheses are true, and assumption underlying the *family-wise error rate* correction methods Glen_B referenced, you can also come at multiple comparison's corrections by controlling the *false discovery rate*—which assumes that some alternative hypotheses may be true—using a several methods: https://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/False_discovery_rate#Controlling_procedures